# Python create folders structure based on current date

Tags: python-2.7

i'm using the following var on my script to send output to one

```
output = "/opt/output"
```

i want to adjust it to make the output relative to the date current date of trigger the script it should be structured like this

```
output = "/opt/output/year/month/day"
```

i'm not sure if i'm using the correct way here i used the following approach

```
output = "/opt/output/" + today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

any tips here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figure it by

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
year = today.strftime("%Y")
month=today.strftime("%m")
day=today.strftime("%d")
output = "/opt/output/"  + year +"/" + month + "/" + day
```

thats worked fine to me

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use the full timestamp instead of just using the date:

```
import os

mydir = os.path.join(output, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d_%H-%M-%S'))
```

It's recommended do it this way because what'd happen if your script runs more than once a day ? You should at least add a counter or something (if you don't want the full timestamp) which will increment some variable if the folder already exist.

You can read more about `os.path.join` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

As per creating a folder, you can do it like this:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(mydir)
```

Comment: based on today day like //opt/output/2017/06/07 always relative to actual date  if the dir is already exist so nothing will happen and script will place some files there

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using `os.path.join` and `os.path.sep`:

```
import os 
.
.
.
full_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, today.strftime('%Y{0}%m{0}%d').format(os.path.sep))
```

Answer (score 0):

`today.strftime('%Y%m%d')` would print todays date as `20170607`. But I guess you want it printed as `2017/06/07`. You could explicitly add the slashes and print it something like this?

`output = "/opt/output/" + today.year +"/" + today.month + "/" + today.date`

Comment: not printing i want to create folders based on today day like //opt/output/2017/06/07  always relative to actual date ,

Comment: I should have been more articulate. The string that is returned from that line would be of the form 20170607.

Comment: i imported the time and datetime but still getting NameError: name 'today' is not defined

Comment: oh, define today as `today = datetime.date.today()` I had assumed you had already done that. apologies.

Comment: still getting error :                                                                                   import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import time


today = datetime.date.today()
output = "/opt/output/" + today.year +"/" + today.month + "/" + today.date

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makesprites.py", line 44, in <module>
    output = "/opt/output/" + today.year +"/" + today.month + "/" + today.date
NameError: name 'today' is not defined

Comment: why do you have `from datetime import datetime` after `import datetime`? Is that necessary?

Comment: Now im getting different error      output = "/opt/output/" + today.year +"/" + today.month + "/" + today.date
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: For that you could just put today.year, today.month and today.date inside the str() function. so it'll be `output = "/opt/output/" + str(today.year) +"/" + str(today.month) + "/" + str(today.date)